# Getting something more than "Error while parsing query. Please check the syntax" in SQL Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am creating a Query Activity in the Automation Studio. The query gives the following message in red:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Error while
>   parsing query. Please check the syntax

One usually gets more information about this in the *Activity* tab of the automation. But what should I do when I cannot even save this query (the step before choosing the destination Data Extension)?

I have gone through [these steps](https://sprignaturemoves.com/troubleshooting-queries-sfmc/) in Adam Spriggs blog. But none of them seem to apply here.

I just need to know more about the query. It seems to work fine on the SQL Server database where it originally comes from.

**UPDATE**: The query code

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.PassengerId,
       a.BookingKey,
       a.FlightId,
       a.Email,
       a.FirstDepartureDateTime,
       a.Origin,
       a.Destination,
       a.FirstName,
       a.LastName,
       a.Gender,
       a.FrequentFlyerId,
       a.HasAncillaries,
       a.HasAncillaryBioFuel
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT t8.BookingKey,
                   t8.Email,
                   t8.PassengerId,
                   t8.FirstDepartureDateTime,
                   t8.FirstName,
                   t8.LastName,
                   t8.FrequentFlyerId,
                   t9.refFirst_FlownTransactionID AS FlightId,
                   Gender,
                   HasAncillaries,
                   HasAncillaryBioFuel,
                   Destination,
                   Origin
   FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT t1.BookingKey,
                      t3.Email,
                      t3.PassengerID,
                      t2.FirstDepartureDateTime,
                      t3.FirstName,
                      t3.LastName,
                      t3.FrequentFlyerId,
                      t3.Gender,
                      t2.HasAncillaries,
                      t2.HasAncillaryBioFuel,
                      t2.Destination,
                      t2.FirstDepartureStation AS Origin
      FROM [Flights] AS t1
      INNER JOIN [Bookings] AS t2 ON (t1.BookingKey = t2.BookingKey)
      INNER JOIN [Customers] AS t3 ON (t1.PassengerID = t3.PassengerID)
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND convert(date,t2.BookingDateTime) = convert(date, dateadd(DAY, -2, getdate()))
        AND IsBooked = 1
        AND IsPassenger = 1
        AND t1.IsCancelled = 0
        AND t1.IsCrew = 0
        AND t1.RBD NOT IN ('I',
                           'Z',
                           'R')
        AND t1.PassengerType NOT IN ('CHD')
        AND t2.SalesChannel <> 'Travel Agency'
        AND t3.IsBRAMember = 1
        AND t3.CommunicationOptIn = 1
        AND t3.FrequentFlyerId = t1.FrequentFlyerId
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t2.BookingDateTime, t2.FirstDepartureDateTime) >= 3
        AND t3.FirstBookingEverKey = t1.BookingKey ) AS t8
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT BookingKey,
                      PassengerID ,
                      FIRST_VALUE(FlownTransactionID) OVER (PARTITION BY BookingKey,
                                                                         PassengerID
                                                            ORDER BY BookingKey,
                                                                     PassengerID,
                                                                     ScheduledDepartureDateTime) AS refFirst_FlownTransactionID
      FROM [Flights]) AS t9 ON (t8.BookingKey = t9.BookingKey
                                       AND t8.PassengerID = t9.PassengerID)
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT t8.BookingKey,
                         t8.Email,
                         t8.PassengerId,
                         t8.FirstDepartureDateTime,
                         NULL AS FirstName,
                         NULL AS LastName,
                         NULL AS FrequentFlyerId,
                         refFirst_FlownTransactionID AS FlightId,
                         Gender,
                         HasAncillaries,
                         HasAncillaryBioFuel,
                         Destination,
                         Origin
   FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT BookingKey,
                      Email,
                      FIRST_VALUE(PassengerID) OVER (PARTITION BY BookingKey
                                                     ORDER BY BookingKey,
                                                              first3CharMatch DESC, CountTrips12M DESC, PassengerID DESC) AS PassengerId,
                                                    FirstDepartureDateTime,
                                                    NULL AS FirstName,
                                                    NULL AS LastName,
                                                    NULL AS FrequentFlyerId,
                                                    Gender,
                                                    HasAncillaries,
                                                    HasAncillaryBioFuel,
                                                    Destination,
                                                    Origin
      FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT t1.BookingKey,
                         t2.BookingDateTime,
                         t2.email_booker,
                         t3.Email,
                         t2.FirstDepartureDateTime,
                         CASE
                             WHEN LEFT(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(t1.PassengerFirstName), 'ø', 'o'), 'å', 'a'), 'ä', 'a'), 'ö', 'o'), 3) = LEFT(t2.email_booker, 3) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                         END AS first3CharMatch,
                         t3.CountTrips12M,
                         t3.IsBRAMember,
                         t1.PassengerID,
                         t1.PassengerFirstName,
                         t3.Gender,
                         t2.HasAncillaries,
                         t2.HasAncillaryBioFuel,
                         t2.Destination,
                         t2.FirstDepartureStation AS Origin
         FROM [Flights] AS t1
         INNER JOIN [Bookings] AS t2 ON (t1.BookingKey = t2.BookingKey)
         INNER JOIN [Customers] AS t3 ON (t1.PassengerID = t3.PassengerID)
         WHERE 1 = 1
           AND convert(date, t2.BookingDateTime) = convert(date, dateadd(DAY, -2, getdate()))
           AND t1.IsBooked = 1
           AND t1.IsPassenger = 1
           AND t1.IsCancelled = 0
           AND t1.IsCrew = 0
           AND t1.RBD NOT IN ('I',
                              'Z',
                              'R')
           AND t1.PassengerType NOT IN ('CHD')
           AND t2.SalesChannel <> 'Travel Agency'
           AND t3.IsBRAMember = 0
           AND t3.Email IS NOT NULL
           AND t3.Email = t2.email_booker
           AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t2.BookingDateTime, t2.FirstDepartureDateTime) >= 3
           AND t3.FirstBookingEverKey = t1.BookingKey) AS t1) AS t8
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT BookingKey,
                      PassengerID ,
                      FIRST_VALUE(FlownTransactionID) OVER (PARTITION BY BookingKey,
                                                                         PassengerID
                                                            ORDER BY BookingKey,
                                                                     PassengerID,
                                                                     ScheduledDepartureDateTime) AS refFirst_FlownTransactionID
      FROM [Flights]) AS t9 ON (t8.BookingKey = t9.BookingKey
                                       AND t8.PassengerID = t9.PassengerID)) a
INNER JOIN [Flights] b ON (a.FlightId=b.FlownTransactionID and a.PassengerId = b.PassengerID)
```

Comment: Can you put the query here? It's hard to tell without looking at it..

Comment: @RachidMamai Sure, sorry! I added the query text.

Comment: Hey DisasterKid, incredible query here. Is this designed to run daily and target recently booked travelers (*with criteria) for an email? If so - I think this query could be simplified.

Comment: @CameronRobert lol. you're damn right. this is someone else's query to be honest.

Comment: @CameronRobert if simplifying the query greenlights in the marketing cloud, feel free to give me a shortcut.

Comment: @Disasterkid, I also work in travel :). Given your data is only coming from 3 tables (Bookings, Customers & Flights), I think you can simplify the query by starting with eligible Flights/Bookings (each day), and then JOIN in the other relevant info. Without seeing the schema & relationships of these 3 tables, I can only speculate how this would look. However, you can also try changing the CONVERT() functions to CAST(). EG: CAST(t2.BookingDateTime as datetime) = CAST(dateadd(DAY, -2, getdate()) as datetime)

Comment: @CameronRobert thanks but i doubt if the `CONVERT` is causing the issue because they've been there when things went well. I just have no clue why this query which is working fine in the local database is not working here.

Comment: @Disasterkid, Salesforce doesn't allow all SQL functions in Query Activities; some very common SQL functions are not allowed in Marketing Cloud. I recommend stepping through your query to find what part has the syntax error. My bet is the FIRST_VALUE or CONVERT functions are to blame.

Comment: CAST and CONVERT are both supported - I would try running it without FIRST_VALUE to see if it validates

Comment: @CameronRobert I will check and come back. I think `FIRST_VALUE` was there before this occurred.

Comment: @zuzannamj  I will check and come back. I think `FIRST_VALUE` was there before this occurred.